# how to write regular expression to match different objects and get the result accordingly?

Tags: python, regex

```
import re
string1 = 'NAME is foo' 
string2 = 'GAME is bar' 
re.findall(r'NAME|GAME(\D*)',str1)
```

Expected output is it should work for either of the keyword and produce the output accordingly like **for string1** it should be **'is foo'** and **for string2** it should be **'is bar'**.

Comment: Your regex can be described as follows: "match a) 'NAME' or b) 'GAME' followed by zero or more non-digits". You want, "match 'NAME' or 'GAME', followed by zero or more non-digits". In both cases the digits are placed in capture group 1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use a non-capturing regex group

```
re.findall(r'(?:NAME|GAME)(\D*)', str1)
```

Answer (score 1):

One more approach

```
items =['NAME is foo' , 'GAME is bar'] 
for item in items:
    print(re.findall(r'(?<=NAME|GAME)\s(.*)',item))
```

**output**

```
['is foo']
['is bar']
```

Here is an explanation of the regex pattern:

```
(?<=NAME|GAME) Look for characters after 'NAME' or 'GAME' (look-behind assertion)
\s             After space (you can include this in the look-behind as (?<=NAME |GAME ) as well)
(.*)           Capturing group (what you are actually looking to capture)
```

Comment: Considering that you are capturing the end of the string in a capture group, why use a positive lookbehind instead of simply a non-capture group `(?:NAME|GAME)`?

Comment: I used `positive look-behind` out of intuition. Is there distinct advantage of using `non-capture group` instead of a `positive look-behind`? When I check the timings (on the sample given here) I get `1.36 µs ± 18.4 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)` with positive look-behind & `1.38 µs ± 29.4 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)` with non-capture group.

Comment: I don't know. I do think a non-capture group reads better here, as one is accustomed to seeing a lookbehind preceding a match that is not captured and a non-capture (or capture) group preceding a match that is captured.